# Computation of Hilbert series involving floor

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, power-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions, hilbert-polynomial

Let $S$ be the graded polynomial ring $k[x_1,x_2]$ such that $x_i$ has degree $i$. Then it's pretty easy to show that $H_S(n)=\text{floor}(n/2)+1$.  Now I'm trying to show that $\sum_{n>0}H_S(n)t^n$ is a rational function. The floor is really throwing me off... it's pretty easy to see that $H(2n)=n+1$ and $H(2n+1)=n+1$, but I'm not sure how to compute power series of floor functions...

The hint given to me is that this rational function has denominator $(1-t)(1-t^2)$

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried splitting it up into two series? $\sum_{n>0}H_S(n)t^n = \sum_{m>0}H_S(2m)t^{2m} + \sum_{m>0}H_S(2m+1)t^{2m+1}$

Comment: So then the series is $\sum_{n>0}H_S(2n)t^{2n}+H_S(2n+1)t^{2n+1}=\sum_{n>0}(n+1)(t+1)t^{2n}$. But this doesn't seem useful either...

Comment: I don't know for what reason you try this way, but in this case the Hilbert series can be computed without knowing the Hilbert function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n = H_S(n)$.  Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n t^n &= \sum_{m \geq 0} a_{2m} t^{2m} + \sum_{m \geq 0} a_{2m+1} t^{2m+1} = \sum_{m \geq 0} (m+1) t^{2m} + \sum_{m \geq 0} (m+1) t^{2m+1}\\
&= (t+1) \sum_{m \geq 0} (m+1) t^{2m} = (t+1) \left(\sum_{m \geq 0} m t^{2m} + \sum_{m \geq 0} t^{2m}\right) \, .
\end{align*}
Now
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m \geq 0} m t^{2m} &= \frac{t}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \sum_{m \geq 0} t^{2m} = \frac{t}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{1 - t^2} = \frac{t}{2} \frac{1}{(1-t^2)^2} \, .
\end{align*}
Thus
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n t^n = (t+1)\left(\frac{t}{2(1-t^2)^2} + \frac{1}{1 - t^2}\right) \, .
\end{align*}